# Error with rclone and google cloud storage coldline

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm getting the following error trying to:

```
`rclone -vv copy /home/hangint3n/google_coldline/test.mp4 hangint3nbackup:`

failed with 1 errors and: 

`googleapi: Error 400: The specified bucket contains a '.' but is not under a currently recognized top-level domain., invalid`
```

I've done a bunch of googling or answers, but it appears that this is not a common problem.

This is my rclone config:

```
   [hangint3nbackup]
    type = google cloud storage
    project_number = 8XXXXXXXXXXX
    object_acl = authenticatedRead
    bucket_acl = authenticatedRead
    location = northamerica-northeast1
    token = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Try changing `hangint3nbackup:` to `hangint3nbackup:REPLACE_WITH_BUCKET_NAME`.

Comment: hangint3nbackup is the bucket name.

Comment: The configured remote is named `hangint3nbackup` also. You must specify the remote and the bucket separate with a colon.

Comment: I go this to work, though I have to do with with public access allow.  Not my prefered option.  rclone -vv copy /home/hangint3n/google_coldline/test.mp4 hangint3nbackup:hangint3nbackup